Setting 2 alternatives paths in Symphony/Twig Twig.yaml
I'm having problems with this =>
Originally the project search in the folder /app/templates/...
But the problem is this, we have to create a new folder (app/Provincia/templates/Thema) and use this folder for ours "distribution" (sorry, I don't know how to call it)
The thing is
I need to make to Twig first search in Provincia/templates/Thema and if not found the template go to /app/templates/.
This is ours yaml >
twig:
    default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/templates'
    globals:
        _knockout_version               : "knockout-3.3.0.debug.js"
        rcdigital_asw_url               : "%env(string:SERVIDOR_ASW)%"
        rcdigital_app_env               : "%env(string:APP_ENV)%"
        twig_default_base               : '%env(string:TWIG_BASE)%'
        twig_base_top                   : '%env(string:TWIG_BASE_TOP)%'
        twig_default_base_externo       : '%env(string:TWIG_BASE_EXTERNO)%'
        twig_theme_app_default_base     : '%env(string:TWIG_THEME_APP_DEFAULT_BASE)%'
        twig_default_boostrap_stg       : '%env(string:TWIG_BOOSTRAP_STG)%'
        twig_default_base_error         : '%env(string:TWIG_BASE_ERROR)%'
        twig_default_base_error_json    : '%env(string:TWIG_BASE_ERROR_JSON)%'


when@test:
    twig:
        strict_variables: true

thanks for the help

According the docs you should use paths to have templates in more tham one place.
paths
type: array default: null
Defines the directories where application templates are stored in addition to the directory defined in the default_path option
# config/packages/twig.yaml 
twig:
    # ...
    paths:
        'email/default/templates': ~
        'backend/templates': 'admin'

Hope it helps.
